# Configuring a .Properties file in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, properties-file

I have tried to use a `Properties` file with **Google App Engine**. I can read a `Properties` file with Google App Engine. But i can't write to a `Properties` file because **FileOutputStream** is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment.

Is there any way to write data to a  `Properties` file with **Google App Engine** ? or any other way to read and write some texts to a file without using datastore ?

Answer (score 1):

Writing data to a file is not supported on App Engine. If you are looking at reading files, then you could ship them with your application or better still in your WEB-INF* folder, so that they are not directly accessible.

If what you are trying to do is just model the properties then do look at the Datastore to model a Property entity. That generic piece of reading/writing properties from a Datastore could help you in other projects too.

In case you want to read/write files, you do have the option of Google Cloud Storage or a Google Drive, the APIs of which are accessible from Google App Engine application but I believe that might be a bit of overkill for what you want. But you do have that option too.